# Can not get images to be displayed in Django template

Tags: python, django

The title is pretty much self explanatory. I did put some images in the static/rakunai folder and added the dirs etc, the whole shebang. I still can't get to display it. I am using docker. Python 3.8 was used and the newest django version was used.

The settings.py:

````
```
"""
Django settings for rakunai project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.12.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'rakunai.urls'

STYLESHEETS='/stylesheets/'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'rakunai.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ['rakunai']
```

templates/aboutus.html:

    {% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!--todo:fix this-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}" type="text/css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Index page</title>
...

    <div class="row rowteams align-tems-center">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 padding-0">
                    <img class="teamimages" src="{% static 'rakunai/img.jpg' %}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 padding-0 skobeloff-bg linen-text">
                    <h2>
                        Simonas Bansevičius
                    </h2>
                    <h5>
                        CEO
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
````

views.py:

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.shortcuts import render

    def index(request):
        return render(request, 'index.html')

    def about(request):
        return render(request, 'about.html')

    def css(request):
        return render(request, 'styles.css')
```

Urlpaterls:

```
    from rakunai.views import index as home
    from rakunai.views import about as details
    from rakunai.views import css

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', home),
        path('about', details),
    ]
```

Any type of feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: The `def css` is not how you return the `styles.css` file. Can you share relevant parts of the `urlpatterns` ([edit] the question).

Answer (score 1):

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'rakunai')]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

in settings.py

```
<img class="teamimages" src="/static/media/img.jpg" %}">
```

in html file

put images in rakunai/media/

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

add this in urls.py

Comment: does not find the file either

Comment: Could it be that docker is messing up my files?

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the `static urls` and `media urls` in your `urls.py`.

Including them would look something like this:-

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path
from rakunai.views import index as home
from rakunai.views import about as details

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home),
    path('about', details),

]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```